# AdMob script not working

Tags: javascript, iphone, admob

I have an HTML file, just with the AdMob code (exactly copied from AdMob website) that was working, but about 3 days ago, the ADs have disappeared, even on test mode. In AdMob site status it shows IDLE, and when I open the URL on my iPod, just a blank screen shows up.

The URL is: http://dinogag.social-dinosaur.com/modules/advertisement.html

I am getting crazy to figure out what is happening, this is the first time that I make an app with AdMob so I am having some difficulties to understand how it works, and how to debug it.

Comment: I opened your link and dont see that there is something like var admob_vars or js link to http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just joined Stack Overflow as well, and this is my first answer :)

I too have had difficulty with AdMob, and I couldn't see any ads after a few days. My best guess as to why ads were not showing up was because after looking at my webapp through a desktop browser so many times, the people at AdMob flagged it as 'not mobile worthy' or something. I had a fill rate of about 8%.

Another problem may be that your page doesn't have enough views.

My suggestion is to, if possible, use a different ad service, such as AdSense. After having the same problem you're having and not getting a straight answer, I gave up and made some fancy (and legal) workarounds to get AdSense for my mobile apps.

Comment: I think that it is the point. I develop the application on my desktop, I just put it on the device to check if it is ok. Can you explain how you made to put AdSense on your app?

Comment: Certainly. Sorry for the late reply. I put the ad with the rest of my website content, and made a menu for choosing apps. When a user runs an app, an iframe opens with the app inside, but the ad is still visible on the bottom of the screen. You can view it in action on my website, though the scheme it a work in progress. http://jsweeneydev.net84.net/apps.php