# Android app has active installs but zero ad revenue

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

My Android app created in AppMakr is not generating ad revenues via AdMob nor AdWhirl although I see it is being actively installed at the Android market. I've tried assigning API keys and Publisher ID on all the right Ad Networks but there is no impact. It is still zero revenue!

I'd appreciate some assistance even it it means incorporating my GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid into my app project. But I do not know how to import that project into eclipse from AppMakr. Any other solutions there? Thanks.

Comment: May I ask how many active installs you currently have? Ad profit really depends on your app content but number of active installs is a main factor.

Comment: Also you can install your app in your own device and test if ad is displaying right. Some apps I saw do not even display their ad correctly.

Comment: Or at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375644/admob-script-not-working/8375698#8375698